# Error in .htaccess file for removing index.php after upgrading to php v5.5

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter framework. I tried to remove index.php, it was success. For some reason I need to upgrade php version to v5.5. Then I copy pasted same code for .htaccess then its not working now. Throws an error like below:

[image]

.htaccess file has following code and its on root folder outside application.

```
<IfModule mysql_auth_module>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "MySQL Member Page"
    Auth_MYSQLhost www.kaoscms.eo
    ## Auth_MYSQLusername grafikkaos_kaoscms
    ## Auth_MYSQLpassword gJcY3xju}:XP
    ## Auth_MYSQLgrp_table
    Auth_MYSQLdatabase grafikkaos_kaoscms
    Auth_MYSQLpwd_table ks_users
    Auth_MYSQLuid_field username_usr
    Auth_MYSQLpwd_field password_usr
    ## Auth_MYSQL_EncryptedPasswords off
    require valid-user
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ admin.php/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^admin/$ admin.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^admin$ admin.php [L]
    #RewriteRule ^install/(.*)$ install.php/$1 [L]
    #RewriteRule ^install/$ install.php [L]
    #RewriteRule ^install$ install.php [L]
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    #RewriteRule ^admin(.*)$ admin.php [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    #RewriteRule ^install(.*)$ install.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Turn on URL rewriting
    RewriteEngine On

    # If your website begins from a folder e.g localhost/my_project then 
    # you have to change it to: RewriteBase /my_project/
    # If your site begins from the root e.g. example.local/ then
    # let it as it is
    RewriteBase /

    # Protect application and system files from being viewed when the index.php is missing
    RewriteCond $1 ^(application|system|private|logs)

    # Rewrite to index.php/access_denied/URL
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/access_denied/$1 [PT,L]

    # Allow these directories and files to be displayed directly:
    RewriteCond $1 ^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|public|assets|content|css|js|images)

    # No rewriting
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [PT,L]

    # Rewrite to index.php/URL
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,it will fix your issue.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```